# EF Core 7 - The LINQ expression 'ProjectionBindingExpression: 14' could not be translated

Tags: .net, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

We migrated from .net 5 to 7 some days ago, and everything was fine until I had to run this query today:

```cs
var query = 
    (from member in organization.Users
    let donor = member.Donor
    select new MembershipVM
    {
        UniqueIdentifier = member.UniqueIdentifier,
        Email = member.Email

        LastDonation = (from donation in donor.Donations
                        where donation.Fund.OrgId == organization.Id
                        orderby donation.timeCreated descending
                        select new MembershipVM.LastDonationVM
                        {
                            Amount = donation.Amount
                        }).FirstOrDefault()
    })
```

I get this exception:

[image]

This same query works fine in EF Core 5 and even 6 without having to do client side evaluation.

An issue is already opened for it on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28125) with more details.

Comment: So what is the question? How to rewrite query into translatable variant?

Comment: It is marked as "Bug" in GitHub tracker, and not fixed, what are you expecting here? Workaround? Apparently we can't fix their bugs.

Comment: Also, if you are seeking for a workaround, provide a full minimal repro - query and the involved entity and view models, configuration etc., basically something that we could copy/paste to a new project and play with it. Because the query you have included currently is not even EF Core LINQ query, but simply in-memory LINQ to Objects query - no `DbContext` or `IQueryable`s involved.

Comment: got you @IvanStoev. And yes, a workaround. I was hoping someone else had the same issue with EFCore.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following workaround:

```cs
var query = 
    from member in organization.Users
    from lastDonation in member.Donor.Donations
        .Where(donation => donation.Fund.OrgId == organization.Id)
        .OrderByDescending(donation => donation.timeCreated)
        .Take(1)
        .Select(donation => new MembershipVM.LastDonationVM
        {
            Amount = donation.Amount
        })
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new MembershipVM
    {
        UniqueIdentifier = member.UniqueIdentifier,
        Email = member.Email

        LastDonation = lastDonation
    };
```